# How to check whether a partitioning is more balanced?

Tags: standard-deviation, percentage, partitioning, wasserstein

For example consider the following two partitions that add approximately to 100 percent.

Partition 1 : 41% 36% 14% 5% 2% 1% <1% <1%

Partition 2 : 82% 10% 4% 3% <1% <1% <1% <1%

Partition 1 is more "balanced"

Is there a numerical metric to compare the two partition's balance measure ?

Answer (score 0):

The most balanced partition would be the one that has equal mass in all bins. So we should compare each partition to the equal-mass one.

The most natural comparison metric would be the [Earth Mover's Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) (EMD), which calculates how much mass needs to be shifted how far to turn one distribution to another one. In your case, Partition 1 will have a smaller EMD to the uniform partition than Partition 2.

The EMD is also known as the [wasserstein](/questions/tagged/wasserstein) metric. You may want to look through the tag.